# UI5 documentation clarification: model definition in UI5

Tags: model, sapui5

In UI5 documentation it is [written](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/4cfa60872dca462cb87148ccd0d948ee):

```js
// set data model
const oData = {
    recipient: {
        name: "World"
    }
};
```

My questions:

1. What does it mean `World` in this context?
2. What value should/can we use here?
3. Should we specify `recipient: {name: "World"}` here at all or the only thing we need to do here is to initialize `new JSONModel(oData)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the following code is only a normal JavaScript object, not model.

```
const oData = {
    recipient: {
        name: "World"
    }
};
```

2.the following code initialize a model.

```
var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
```

After this initialization, you can get/set any properties of this model

```
var oRecipient = oModel.getProperty("/recipient");
var sName = oModel.getProperty("/recipient/name");

oModel.setProperty("/recipient",{"name":"abc"});
oModel.setProperty("/recipient/name","abc");
```